# Removing overlapping parts of polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features

I have many polygons with overlaps.

I want to remove the part of overlapping that is between polygons.

I tried `Symmetrical difference`, it gives me only the area overlapping and not two polygons.

Red polygons are overlapping

[image: example]
[image]

Comment: try using dissolve

Comment: Not help, but Thanks

Comment: what outcome do you expect? You want to remove the overlapping polygons or to separate them from the others in another layer?

Comment: I want to remove the area that overlapping between polygons

Comment: Compute difference A-B and keep the result, and then B-A and keep the result.

Comment: added the one more image for example, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a **union without the optional layer**

[image]

you get your polygons splitted on the overlap

Then you need to run the algoritm '**join attributes by location (summary)**'

[image]

Choose **'****equals**' as predicate.  Select one field (eg. id) as field to summarise.  Check 'count' as summaries to calculate.

After running 'join attributes by location (summary)' you need to **select the polygons with 'count_id = 1'** and save them as a new layer.

Comment: Thank you, is working and look like what I want, I did another way, v.clean, after calculated area and delete the polygons, but your way very good, again Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to take the difference between your two layers. You may need to run the operation twice (for A-B and B-A) then join the results if you intend to have all of the data in the same layer.
 [image]

Comment: I need like Symmetrical Difference, please see one more image that attached, Thank you